# Proper use UpdateSecretRequest in Amaon's java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am using the code below to update a secret in Amazon's secret manager service.  Shortly after I update the secret value, I retrieve the secret from AWS, and it isn't the most recently updated value.  The code below doesn't throw an exceptions.  I am looking for best practices on how to confirm an update to AWS secret manager is successful.

```
public void updateSecretValue(String fullAwsKey, String keyValue) {
    UpdateSecretRequest updateSecretRequest = new UpdateSecretRequest ().withSecretId(fullAwsKey);
    updateSecretRequest.setSecretString(keyValue);
    
    AWSSecretsManager client = buildAWSSecretsManager();
    try {
        performUpdate(updateSecretRequest, client);
    } catch (SdkClientException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        client.shutdown();
    }
}

protected void performUpdate(UpdateSecretRequest updateSecretRequest, AWSSecretsManager client) {
    boolean processed = false;
    int tryCount = 0;
    while (!processed) {
        UpdateSecretResult result = client.updateSecret(updateSecretRequest);
        if (result.getSdkHttpMetadata().getHttpStatusCode() == 200) {
            processed = true;
        } else {
            tryCount++;
            if (tryCount >= 5) {
                throw new RuntimeException("performUpdate, unable to update secret: " + result.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the older V1 API. Amazon recommends using AWS SDK for Java 2.x, which is a major rewrite of the 1.11.x code base built on top of Java 8+. Java SDK 2.x has improved consistency, ease of use, and strongly enforced immutability. It also has support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.

Here is the Secret Manager V2 examples:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager/src/main/java/com/example/secrets

If you are not familiar with getting up and running with V2 APIs, then please refer to this topic that will explain it:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)